# Map with multiple keys mapped to a single value in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary

What I need is a Map that maps multiple keys to a single value (3 keys to 1 value in my case) such that 3 keys together uniquely identifies a value. This can easily be done with nested Maps such as:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<Double, Object>>> map = new HashMap<>();
Object value = map.get("foo").get(3).get(1.23);
```

However, I also want to be able to get a list of values by only using some of the keys, such as:

```
List<Object> values1 = map.get("foo");       // All values with "foo" as its String-key
List<Object> values2 = map.get(3).get(1.23); // All values with 3 as its Integer-key AND 1.23 as its Double-key
```

Is there a class in Java that implements such a datastructure or if not, how would I go about doing it myself?

Comment: Could be possible to concatenate all your values into a single key: `map.put(key1 + "-" + key2 + "-" + key3, "SomeValue");`. Else I can't think of a way other than having 3 maps where each has a deeper nested map structure

Comment: It sounds like a database table doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new class and have these 3 keys as attributes such as

```
class CompositeKey {
    private String key1;
    private Integer key2;
    private Double key3;


    public CompositeKey(String key1, Integer key2, Double key3) {
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
        this.key3 = key3;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((key1 == null) ? 0 : key1.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((key2 == null) ? 0 : key2.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((key3 == null) ? 0 : key3.hashCode());
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        CompositeKey other = (CompositeKey) obj;
        if (key1 == null) {
            if (other.key1 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!key1.equals(other.key1))
            return false;
        if (key2 == null) {
            if (other.key2 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!key2.equals(other.key2))
            return false;
        if (key3 == null) {
            if (other.key3 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!key3.equals(other.key3))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public String getKey1() {
        return key1;
    }

    public Integer getKey2() {
        return key2;
    }

    public Double getKey3() {
        return key3;
    }

}
```

Then I'll create 3 index maps for each key as follow

```
// 3 index maps
// List<CompositeKey> not just CompositeKey because one key say k1 can be in combination of 2 different set of k2 and k3.
Map<String, List<CompositeKey>> key1Index = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, List<CompositeKey>> key2Index = new HashMap<>();
Map<Double, List<CompositeKey>> key3Index = new HashMap<>();
```

Then the data map where actual data will be kept

```
Map<CompositeKey, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Now, say you want to add `key1`,`key2`,`key3` against `Object`. Create `CompositeKey` object as key

```
CompositeKey compositeKey = new CompositeKey(key1, key2, key3);

// Change value accordingly below
dataMap.put(compositeKey, new Object());
```

Also, update the index maps so that you can use them to look up later

```
key1Index.computeIfAbsent(key1, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(compositeKey);
key2Index.computeIfAbsent(key2, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(compositeKey);
key3Index.computeIfAbsent(key3, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(compositeKey);
```

Finally, you can now,

```
// Search by single key, say key1
        List<CompositeKey> list = key1Index.get(key1);
        List<Object> result = getResult(list, dataMap);

        // Search by two keys, say key 1 and key 2
        List<CompositeKey> key1IndexResult = key1Index.get(key1);
        List<CompositeKey> key1Key2List = key1IndexResult.stream()
            .filter(ck -> ck.getKey2().equals(key2))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Object> key1Key2Result = getResult(key1Key2List, dataMap);

        // Search by all 3 keys
        CompositeKey allKeys = new CompositeKey(key1, key2, key3);
        List<Object> allKeysResult = getResult(Collections.singletonList(allKeys), dataMap);
```

Utility method used:

```
private List<Object> getResult(List<CompositeKey> list, Map<CompositeKey, Object> dataMap) {
        return list.stream().map(dataMap::get)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Working code online link: https://onlinegdb.com/rk2kszLMN

Answer (score 0):

There is no interface in the standard library that meets your needs. I think you've got the right approach already, here's a simple class that expands on it:

```
import static java.util.Collections.emptyMap;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class ThreeMap<K1, K2, K3, V> {

    Map<K1, Map<K2, Map<K3, V>>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public V get(K1 a, K2 b, K3 c) {
        return map.getOrDefault(a, emptyMap()).getOrDefault(b, emptyMap()).get(c);
    }

    public V put(K1 a, K2 b, K3 c, V v) {
        return map.computeIfAbsent(a, mapProvider()).computeIfAbsent(b, mapProvider()).put(c, v);
    }

    public Collection<V> getAllValues(K1 a) {
        return map.getOrDefault(a, emptyMap()).entrySet().stream().flatMap(e -> e.getValue().values().stream()).collect(toList());
    }

    public Collection<V> getAllValues(K1 a, K2 b) {
        return map.getOrDefault(a, emptyMap()).getOrDefault(b, emptyMap()).entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getValue()).collect(toList());
    }

    private <K, A, B> Function<K, Map<A, B>> mapProvider() {
        // for convenient use in computeIfAbsent
        return k -> new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe there seems like a classic DB table with 4 columns, where 3 of the columns would be the key. So, I would go ahead and create a custom key with the three different types.

```java
public class CompositeKey {

    public String stringKey;

    public Integer integerKey;

    public Long longKey;

}
```

It's up to you to model the contraints of the different subkeys, e.g. if all of them are required. If you implement equals and hashCode then a simple `Map<CompositeKey,Object>` would solve the simple query.

For the other query types you would have to implement an own repository and decide whether to add an index to that query or nor. For example, if you wish to obtain all values with a specific `Integer` value and have no index, you would have to do a full scan (iterate over all entries in the map). If you wish to replicate the function of a DB index, you would then have to hold maps from a subset of the keys to the list of possible values. In this case, you cannot use the map directly and would have to perform all operations (`put`, `get`, etc.) by using your repository implementation.